How to change the global axis in graph editor
Is there a way where we can change the global to local axis or local to global axis.
Sometimes I want just the bone to be rotated or moved in the local axis but when I do that I move the bones on global axis

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am having a problem is that when I move a particular axis of the bone like suppose a y-axis I want to move in local axis in graph editor and when I do that I can only move the y-axis in global axis instead of local axis. Is there a way to change the global to local axis in graph editor. I sometimes needs to move the bones in local axis in graph editor but I can only move in global axis :"(
